# How do I make this python unittest run faster? Less than a second

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

This is a bit of code that should run in less than a second.
It counts the number of filled dots in the page.
Is there any faster way to do this?

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver


class CountFilled(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()

    def test_count_filled(self):
        self.driver.get("http://apply.dataprocessors.com.au/")
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form/p[1]/input").send_keys("PO65")
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form/p[3]/input").send_keys("{}".format(self.driver.page_source.count('"fi')))
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form/p[4]/input").click()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Looks to me the delay is probably caused by fetching the page. Parhaps download the page and fetch it from a local hard disk?

Comment: Just doing the `self.driver.get("http://apply.dataprocessors.com.au/")` takes almost two  seconds on my machine

Comment: Less than a second on what hardware?

Comment: On my machine an i5 toshiba laptop.

Comment: Nah... it works just fine. I just did it. It doesn't matter that it takes 2 seconds to launch the page, the timer isn't going to start until the page loads anyway. The whole point of this exercise is that YOU are able to do it so you can apply for the job. Kinda defeats the purpose when you get others to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

There a lot of things that can impact the performance of the test execution. In terms of finding the element try to avoid xpath as that's known to give the slowest performance in many cases. Use id or css instead. In terms of driver you are using headless already which is the fastest out there.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the css selectors. It did not do it for me.

Comment: I am afraid. this test is very simple and I do not see much to improve here. Probably the slowness is application side and there is nothing to do with WebDriver

Comment: I agree. Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

Counting all the instances of the string "fi" in the entire HTML source is probably not the most efficient (or accurate) way to do this... :)

I did this and it worked... and I applied for your job... lol j/k

Java

```
driver.get("http://apply.dataprocessors.com.au/");
driver.findElement(By.name("jobref")).sendKeys("PO65");
List<WebElement> dots = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("img[src='filled_O.gif']"));
driver.findElement(By.name("value")).sendKeys(String.valueOf(dots.size()));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='Submit']")).click();
```

python (I think this is right... or close, I don't know python)

```
self.driver.get("http://apply.dataprocessors.com.au/")
self.driver.find_element_by_name("jobref").send_keys("PO65")
dots = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img[src='filled_O.gif']")
self.driver.find_element_by_name("value").send_keys(len(dots)) // does len(dots) need to be converted to a string?
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[value='Submit']").click()
```

Basically I'm using a CSS selector to fetch the number of IMG tags that contain the filled O gif.

Comment: Thanks JeffC. I won't apply to the job. I tried your approach in python it still exceeds 1 sec.

Comment: That's really strange. I've run the Java code several times and it's worked each time and I'm just using the Firefox driver.